# Sorry ....., it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later! -- Bootstrap & aws s-3 (hosting)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a static website build using bootstrap.  I am hosting the website in amazon aws s3.

Whenever i click the send for the contact form i am getting the following error

```
"Sorry ....., it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"

Email it sending is the contact details is "support@<domain-name>.com"
```

I tried by replacing the email with my gmail account.  It didn't work wither.

Comment: Bootstrap and S3 have nothing to do with email.

Comment: Thank you tedder42 for your time.  Then why i am getting the error message.  What might the reason..?
The reason why i thought it might be related to s3 is due to hosting a static website.  I am not sure if the contact.php file will work there.

Comment: contact.php is not static, it would need to be executed. S3 is static.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at contact_me.php file in mail directory. Form will submit your data to contact_me.php file and this php page will use the standard php [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. I am not sure how php works on amazon, but you can start [here](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/).